# Javascript code doesn't work when I use onsubmit instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submit'),
    div = document.getElementById('div');

div.onmouseover = function sum() {
    value1 = document.getElementById('form').value;
    value1 = document.getElementById('form2').value;

    sum = value1 + value2;
}

submit.onsubmit = function print() {
    div.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

For some reason, the code doesn't work; however, if I replace the last with

```
submit.onclick = function print() {
    div.innerHTML = sum;
}
```

`onclick` instead of `onsubmit`, it works perfectly fine, even though `sum` was calculated outside and before I press submit. It's as if every variable becomes `null` when I enter submit even though the variables aren't even stored in the form fields.

Comment: What kind of element is `document.getElementById('submit')`? `submit` events are only triggered on `form` elements.

Answer (score 1):

The `onsubmit` event handler must be attached to the `form` element, not to `input` element.

Assuming you have a `form`, you could do

```
submit.form.onsubmit = ...
```

Comment: @Matthew: *"it doesn't work"* is not a helpful problem or error description. My toaster doesn't work either. Please be more precise, then we can provide better help.

Comment: And the HTML would be useful so that we don't have to guess. In fact a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem would probably ensure a good solution is given.

Answer (score 0):

The `onsubmit` event fires on the form element, not the button.  Try moving the `onsubmit` handler to the form instead

Comment: i tried form.form.onsubmit and it still doesn't work. it works if i write submit.onclick though.

Comment: submit.form.onsubmit doesn't work; submit.onsubmit doesn't work